# Are these screws for bracket enough to support adult queen bed?

Tags: bedroom, design

Picture of bottom right corner showing the foot board and side rail connected with the bracket, and the bed, at https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNIOH.jpg and couple more pictures https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSCv.jpg.

The brackets are https://amzn.to/37PJbA3. The smaller screws that came with it were about 1/2" but I used 1 1/4" instead. The wood is pine, 1.5" thick.

My concern is whether these screws will shear or will get pulled out of the wood, after a long time of using the bed (frequent getting in and off loads, tossing and turning over night, etc.). I was wondering if I should switch these to structural screws of the same size, or bolts/nuts/washers so that they go all the way through these vertical side rails and can't be pulled out of the bed.

I asked someone at a big box store and he said what I have should be more than enough and the small screws are just used to secure the brackets to the wood and not really carrying the load, but I figure of course they are carrying the load being transferred from the brackets. He also said drilling all the way through for bolts may split the wood.

Comment: This is a store bought bed, right? I guess the manufacturer made sure, that all stuff used is just strong enough to support the bed for several years.

Comment: Sorry, it is a homemade bed.

Answer (score 1):

What is the diameter of the screws or size?  1-1/4" screws will have plenty of withdrawal strength and since there are 4 or 5 you really don’t need more than 3/4”. Wood screws that will fit the holes will provide plenty of strength. Since you have 1-1/4” those brackets will be stronger than the 2 pins they hang on.

Comment: the screws are #6 zinc wood screws. I hope so! Thanks

Comment: They may be zinc-coated, but they aren't zinc.